# Sending Queue Message on Artemis using C#

Tags: c#, activemq-artemis, sender

I am actually trying to send a queue message on Artemis using C#.
An instance is being created but not as I would like and when I check the queue message, it says 0. Also I want to add an expiry date and set the Routing_Type to ANYCAST, but cannot see where to specify those details.

Find below my actual code, where I tried setting an expiry date of 5minutes;

```
        private static void SendMsgAtemis()
        {
            string address = "amqp://tst01sacmamq.corporate.intra:61616";

            Connection connection = new Connection(new Address(address));
            Session session = new Session(connection);

            SenderLink sender = new SenderLink(session, "test-sender", "Nad-Test");

            Message message1 = new Message("Hello AMQP!");
            TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0);
            sender.Send(message1, ts);


            Console.WriteLine("Message sent into queue Nad-Test");
        }
```

When running the above, the instance is being created as shown, but as you can see, the Queue message is indicating 0;

[image]

Can anyone advise on the above? 
***Nad-Test*** has been created but no Queue Count and it is in MultiCast mode.

Comment: Did you configure the `Nad-Test` address in your `broker.xml` or did the broker auto-create it for you?

Comment: @JustinBertram it got created when I sent my message.

Answer (score 0):

With .NET Client for ActiveMQ Artemis, it should be as simple as that:

```
var connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory();
var endpoint = Endpoint.Create("tst01sacmamq.corporate.intra", 61616);
var connection = await connectionFactory.CreateAsync(endpoint);

var producer = await connection.CreateProducerAsync("Nad-Test", RoutingType.Anycast);
var msg = new Message("Hello AMQP!")
{
    TimeToLive = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)
};
await producer.SendAsync(msg);
```

This Client is based on AmqpNetLite but it handles all the ActiveMQ Artemis minutiae for you.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/ArtemisNetClient

https://havret.github.io/dotnet-activemq-artemis-client/